# Creating membership based website using drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Using drupal,I am creating a registration based website that has four membership plans.
Based on the selected membership plan, users have to pay the membership fee using any payment module.
How can I create membership plans and this kind of payment functionality?

Comment: I want to select the membership plan before going to registration page.

Answer (score 2):

There is a module called lm_Paypal http://drupal.org/project/lm_paypal . Use that module . This module can assign change roles of users also, after payment

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of following links for creating membership website using drupal :
You have to use ubercart for this.

1) http://10kwebdesign.com/10kblog/step-step-setting-membership-community-site-using-drupal

2) http://www.leveltendesign.com/blog/rachel/how-create-memberships-drupal-ubercart#.UPjnmsXMgqY

If you are willing to pay for it then just go for "Membership suite module" on http://www.moneyscripts.net/. This is a paid module and is well documented.